# Nextjs Production server Capacity

Tags: next.js

Will it be enough 16 GB with 2 CPU for a production environemnt of NextJs application ?
Is there any chance to go down or stop the nodejs if more than 100 customer access the site ?

Comment: It should be sufficient in most cases unless you have some heavy data operations I would recommend checking the usage by simulating 10 to 20 customers then you will have an idea how much resources your app might consume

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any tools available to check it ?

Answer (score 0):

For running `node` backend with maximum processing cores , using `pm2` is recommended.

Read [this](https://dev.to/reactstockholm/setup-a-next-js-project-with-pm2-nginx-and-yarn-on-ubuntu-18-04-22c9) article for instructions.